# morgan skip not working

Tags: express, browser-refresh, morgan

Building an express app with `morgan 1.9.0` and `browser-refresh 1.7.2`.

Morgan seems to be ignoring the `skip` option. My app is initialized with

```
const skipFcn = (req, res) => req.path.startsWith('/static/views')
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('test:', skipFcn(req, res))
  next()
})
app.use(morgan('combined', {
  skip: skipFcn
}))
```

But in my logs I'm still getting hundreds of hits from `browser-refresh`:

```
test: true
::1 - - [14/Oct/2017:10:09:07 +0000] "GET /static/views/project$0.0.0/views/components/service-form.marko.jsHTTP/1.1" 200 3748 "http://localhost:4002/admin/services" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: I tried your example myself and it seems to work for me. The only thing I can think of is that the log line is coming from somewhere else. Try commenting out the `app.use(morgan(...` bit to confirm it's the only logging in play here. If it isn't something simple like that I suggest attaching the Chrome debugger to your Node and stepping through.

Comment: I also got the same issue

Answer (score 6):

I use the following code and it worked

```
app.use(morgan('combined', {skip: (req, res) => {return req.originalUrl.startsWith('/src')}));
```

You probably want to try it and see if it works on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking in here.

I've been having the same problem. I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong, and after far longer than it should have been, I went into `node_modules/morgan/index.js` and on line 80, added the following:

```js
console.log('SKIP FUNCTION:', skip.toString());
```

This immediately showed the secret location in *my project* where I was also configuring Morgan, which was clobbering the new place where I was trying to configure Morgan (again).

After deleting my legacy configuration, morgan skip function started working beautifully.